# How can check the duplication on the group level?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I check for duplicated groups and remove them? Here is my data frame:

```
Group     Value_1      Value_2
 A          17           0.1
 A          20           0.8
 A          22           0.9
 A          24           0.13

 B          17           0.1
 B          20           0.8
 B          22           0.9
 B          24           0.13

 C          17           0.1
 C          20           0.8
 C          22           0.9
 C          26           0.11
```

In this data frame group A and B are duplicate where as C is not because its forth element is different and thus it is deeper to be unique not duplicate, the resultant data frame should look like this:

```
Group     Value_1      Value_2
 A          17           0.1
 A          20           0.8
 A          22           0.9
 A          24           0.13


 C          17           0.1
 C          20           0.8
 C          22           0.9
 C          26           0.11
```

I tried to groupby and check for duplicates, but this will check the values on the observational level. How can check the duplication on the group level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `frozenset`, then remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) (by default by all columns) and get indices - all groups names:

```
idx = df.groupby('Group').agg(frozenset).drop_duplicates().index
#alternative solution
idx = df.groupby('Group').agg(tuple).drop_duplicates().index
```

Or reshape to by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
g = df.groupby('Group').cumcount()
idx = df.set_index(['Group',g]).unstack().drop_duplicates().index
```

Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = df[df['Group'].isin(idx)]
print (df)
   Group  Value_1  Value_2
0      A       17     0.10
1      A       20     0.80
2      A       22     0.90
3      A       24     0.13
8      C       17     0.10
9      C       20     0.80
10     C       22     0.90
11     C       26     0.11
```